# "bonne continuation de X" vs. "bonne continuation dans X"

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

Does one say "bonne continuation *de* X" or "bonne continuation *dans* X".

Examples (at the end of an email):

- bonne continuation *de* votre projet
- bonne continuation *dans* votre projet

I have seen both phrases being used:

- https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=bonne+continuation+dans+
- https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=bonne+continuation+de+

Answer (score 4):

Both will do; in the first case the continuation itself is rather what is meant , in the second what is meant is the drive of whoever is involved in the project to go on with it. These two alternative ways in the end amount to well-wishing for both the project and the succes of those involved in it in making it progress, as the two are inseparable.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct and similar, as you can see on this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bonne%20continuation%20de%2Cbonne%20continuation%20dans&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbonne%20continuation%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbonne%20continuation%20dans%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbonne%20continuation%20de%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbonne%20continuation%20dans%3B%2Cc0):

[image: ngram]

They are constantly fighting even if it seems that “bonne continuation de X” is older and still more common to use.

Comment: Ce ngram contient un nombre insuffisant d'occurences, dont la « grande » majorité utilise « dans » pour indiquer un lieu. Ça n'apporte absolument rien.